# Image issue in cPanel

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, cpanel

I have installed a WordPress free theme and imported the demo content on the live server. That time image is not showing correctly. Please check the error

**When I have clicked on the image view button from cPanel:**

[image]

While importing the demo content on my local server the images are correctly showing. I have tried to change file permission of upload folder and updated the `max_execution_time = 300` in php.ini

**Media Library:**

[image]

My phpinfo: http://prntscr.com/kb9t9m

Comment: try checking by uploading one image from your local folder, if it works then demo images are having some problem

Comment: Yeh, when I have to upload the image from my local folder it's working.

Comment: then it is the problem with demo content images, something is broken in it

Comment: @charankumar demo images are working in my local server, they have issue with cPanel, Please check the link http://prntscr.com/kb9wsk